# What's the difference between unlinked_binary and bytecode?

Tags: solidity, compilation

I have two different projects. In one, the `build/token.json` file contains an `unlinked_binary` field. In the other, there's no `unlinked_binary`, but there's `bytecode`.

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

It's about [Library Linking](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/using-the-compiler.html#library-linking). To perform a call to an `external` or `public` function defined in a library the compiler must know the address of the library. If you do not provide it using the `--libraries` option, the compiler will insert a temporary address placeholder instead. You can do linking separately to eliminate these placeholders.

`unlinked_binary` is bytecode that still contains placeholders while `bytecode` is the final bytecode that does not have any and can actually be deployed.